# How to outline a region in a surface plot in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, scatter-plot, surface

I have a 2D array `data` and I plot it using `surf`. In the surface plot, there is a region in which the elements in `data` are greater than `0.9*max(max(data))`. I want to 'outline' the region. How can I do that?

If I type

```
data_copy = data;
data_copy(data<0.9) = nan;
```

Then if I use scatter plot together with the original surface plot to plot the coordinates of `data_copy` that are not nan, I can 'shade' the region. But I just want the 'boundary' of the region. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that this is exactly what you want, but you can try the following: consider a simple example - `f(x,y)=sin(2 pi x)`. You can remove edges from your plot (if you have a lot of data, it looks messy). Then, you can explicitly set the colors: draw the region of interest with one color, and all the other data with other:

```
data=repmat(sin(2*pi*(0:0.01:1)),numel(0:0.01:1),1); %define data
s=surf(data) % plot
s.EdgeAlpha=0; % remove edges
s.CData(data>=0.9*max(max(data)))=0; %set the color for the region of interest
s.CData(data<0.9*max(max(data)))=1; %set different color for all other data
```

Now it is clear, where your boundary is.

Comment: I usually set `view(2)` as I just want to see how the colour varies in different position. In your example, I want to see either two vertical lines or two horizontal lines (or both) for the boundary, and inside that boundary I want to see the normal colour as usual.

Comment: Do you need 3D plot at all (surf)? You can use contour plot and explicitly set contours of interest

Comment: The plot I have consists of both oscillating +ve and -ve part (like a wave). If I use contour and only show the specified contour level, I still end up with lots of 'circles' on the plots, but they are all tightly grouped together in a region of a plot. I want an outline of that region, not lots of circles.